# What's the name of the music played during the final battle of Tokyo Ghoul √A episode 9?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What is the name of the music playing from 20.00 to the end of the episode in Tokyo Ghoul √A episode 9?

Comment: [Four more days.](http://vgmdb.net/album/50263)

Comment: You may go and search the OST CD on amazon.co.jp. For some music CDs, they allow users to listen to the first few seconds of each track.

Answer (score 1):

That song's name is [Das zweite Kapitel (disc #1, track #26)](http://vgmdb.net/album/50263).

Comment: Welcome to the site, you might want to add some more detail to your answer. In this case, at least a link to a Youtube video might be helpful for example.

Comment: @mivilar Yes, but a YouTube video also often gets taken down real quick. I would suggest linking to a website like amazon or [vgmdb](http://vgmdb.net/) where they list the album's information. :)